# What is this hacker trying to achieve?

Tags: hacking

I have hundreds of lines like this in my syslog from many different ip addresses:

```
Oct 16 17:03:06 example named[857]: client @0x7fa2dc083e40 104.190.220.183#3075 (sl): query (cache) 'sl/ANY/IN' denied
Oct 16 17:03:06 example named[857]: client @0x7fa2d812bc70 90.196.21.194#80 (sl): query (cache) 'sl/ANY/IN' denied
```

a reverse dns on 104.190.220.183 gave Hostname: 104-190-220-183.lightspeed.tukrga.sbcglobal.net.
a reverse dns on 90.196.21.194 gave Hostname: 5ac415c2.bb.sky.com.

What is this hacker trying to achieve and should I be concerned as the attempt is denied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind: query (cache) './ANY/IN' denied - is it a DDos attack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1049513/bind-query-cache-any-in-denied-is-it-a-ddos-attack)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.